# IEnumerable<XElement>.Value() extension method available in VB.Net but not C#?

Tags: c#, vb.net, extension-methods, ienumerable, xelement

In VB.Net you can easily get the text value of the first child element of an XElement like so:

```
Dim sChildValue = xeParent.<MyChild>.Value()
```

Of course that  syntax is not supported in C#, but it produces the same IEnumerable(Of XElement) result as the Elements() method. So we can rewrite the above like so:

```
Dim sChildValue = xeParent.Elements("MyChild").Value()
```

This Value() extension method is handy because often you are working with small XML documents and you just want the first node that matches. (One thing that annoys me about this method is that it seems to return Nothing/null if the IEnumerable list is empty due to the specified element not being  found. To work around this I have created my own ValueOrBlank() method that returns an empty string in that situation instead.)

My problem is that I can't do the same thing in C#:

```
var sChildValue = xeParent.Elements("MyChild").Value(); // won't compile, can't find Value() method
```

I checked my references/imports and they match the VB.Net project where the same call works. Fortunately I am able to use my custom ValueOrBlank() extension method to accomplish the same thing. But I'm curious as to what's missing in my C# project. I tried right-clicking on the Value() method call in Visual Studio and clicking "Go To Definition" to see if the Object Browser could tell me where the extension method is kept, but it just shows  the System.String class. Does that mean this is one of those sneaky VB.Net-only features that the compiler itself supports, like the XML Axis < MyChild > syntax?

Comment: the fact that it returns "Nothing" instead of empty string is a feature, not a bug -- it should arguably throw an "object reference...instance..." exception, since you are trying to get the value of the first element, which is not there; but returning Nothing is a nice improvement over that, while still allowing you to distinguish between "no match" and "match with no value".

Comment: @Abacus, in the strict sense, yes, I agree that trying to get a value of the first element of an empty sequence should throw an exception. But this Value() extension method that returns an empty string is a nice convenience in many scenarios, particularly UI/display logic where optional fields are being rendered. (A similar example is jQuery's "fluent" style, where a selector can return an empty list, but most of the methods still work, even chained.) No big deal, I was able to my own custom extension method to achieve the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.Value()` described in link you gave is not an extension method, it's a property and it's specific to VB.net (like any other axis properties: ., ..., @Attribute, (indexer))

Comment: I couldn't find the documentation for it anywhere, but GSerg found it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384768.aspx. Funny, I always assumed it was an extension method because it showed up in the same color as other extension methods in Intellisense. But you're absolutely right, it is labelled "Property".

Answer (score 0):

You need to get a *single* element:

```
var value = parent.Element("MyChild").Value;
```

Comment: This is not the same; will throw a NullReferenceException if "MyChild" is not present, as `Element` will return `null`. VB's `Value()` is a true extension method that is [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384768.aspx) to accept a sequence and return `.Value` of the first element of the sequence (or empty string if the sequence is empty).

Comment: Yes, you're right GSerg, it's not the same thing. And thank you for the link to MSDN, I couldn't find the official documentation until now. To me this indicates that IEnumerable(Of XElement).Value() is in the same category as the XML Axis syntax, which is specific to VB.Net (even though you could easily implement it in C# without compiler changes.) I'm going to write an answer with this information.